# Double Slash at end of URL when going to HTTPS?

Tags: php, html, session, slash

My site currently uses http and https sections based on the data being collected on the site (form data uses https).

On my index page, I have the PHP code at the top:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    ob_start();
    if( $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) {
        header('Location:http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])); 
        die();
    } 
?>
```

However, the page will not load and I get a 404 error. Similarly, when i visit the sections with https security using the head code:

```
<?php
session_start();
ob_start();
    if( $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 80) {
        header('Location:https://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']).'/'.basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])); 
        die();
    }
?>
```

The site does not respond AND for some reason creates a double slash when switching from http to https.

Example: http://www.abc.com/, then clicking button which should route to enroll.php shows http://www.abc.com//enroll.php

why the need for the double slash and can anybody help with the 404 errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dirname()` won't work on `PHP_SELF` because that is not necessarily a full directory.

`dirname("/enroll.php")` will correctly return an empty string, which in turn leads to the double `//`.

What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Well - I have the 'exact' same formula on another site and it does function (see www.aabbenefits.com - if you click Contact Us, it redirects to https and you'll see the double slash) so not sure why this site malfunctions.

I want my non secure pages to stay http whereas the secure pages need https. I am using forms on the secure pages which collect payment and ssn information.

Comment: @J M the point remains that the method you use to build the URL is flawed (whether or not it is the reason for the 404). Have you tried `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]`?

Comment: not yet - I apologize I am not very advanced so what are you suggesting I replace with $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]?

When i run a simple 'echo' statement in the middle of the page at question:
<?php echo $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; ?>
It simply returns as slash /

Comment: Pekka - I think I see what you are saying now. I replaced the following:
header('Location:https://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']).'/'.basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));

with
  header('Location:https://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);

this removed the double slash!

I am still unable to figure out this darned 404 error however ;)

Comment: @J M 4 so that persists? Strange. Can you show an exact URL that causes a 404? Can you make a test output of the URL by not outputting it in `header()` but using `echo()` and `die()`?

Comment: What Pekka's saying is: Use $_SERVER['Request_URI'] instead of dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']).'/'.basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])

Comment: !Pekka - I'm a bit hesistant to post the full URl on the board but am literally just running the exact example as above. What is even more strange is when I run the code locally it works - when i upload to server it doesnt (site B - www.aabbenefits.com) does though

when i ran the following echo statement:
<?php
session_start();
ob_start();
 if( $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 80) {
  echo('Location:https://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]); 
        die();
 }
?>


I returned:
Location:https://localhost/designtest/enroll.php

Comment: @grossvogel - thanks I did do that and it removed the double slash. I am now running into issues however with a site 404 which makes no sense because I KNOW the file exists in the directory.

If I remove the ob_start() function from the following code, everything works but not if left in.
<?php
session_start();
ob_start();
 if( $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 80) {
  echo('Location:https://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]); 
        die();
 }
?>

Comment: @J M I'm off now, one more thing, try putting the `header()` and `die()` commands in front of `session_start()` and `ob_start()`, if possible in the very first line. Good luck. 'night!

Comment: good lord - my server configuration didn't have SSL enabled - this was the cause of the 404 error. Thanks for all your help! The double slashes have been removed!